# Python Matchstick Game

Tags: python, function, return, game-theory

I need to make a matchsticks game but it has to be a simple way. I dont know how to start. I couldn't handle it, can you help me? Everything I tried was complicated and long. And I'm sorry for my English, I'm not native. I need to start this like.

```
def win(count_sticks):
```

We have a two player. At each turn, the player can remove minimum 1, max 3 matchsticks. The player who chooses the last matchstick wins.For example, if the game has 1, 2, or 3 matchsticks, the current player can win by taking them all. For example, if the game has 4 matchsticks, the current player cannot be guaranteed to win.

Starting with the count_sticks to the current player If a win can be guaranteed returns True otherwise False

Comment: Please show your work, even if it is wrong or not working at all.

Comment: def win(count_sticks):

Comment: Thank you for sharing this line of code, but I need more work to be shown so that I can help you better. Please try to write any piece of code even if you think that it is totally wrong.